# Native sql query location

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I have an Spring+Hibernate application. For some actions I need to use native sql. My question is where can I store sql queries. I don't want to hardcode them. I want to know existed approaches. I also want to see examples, so relevant links will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by I don't want to hard code them? I hope you realize that change in query requires add few more lines of code to extract results from result set and populate java object.

Comment: I mean that I don't want to put queries into my java code.

Comment: Stored procedures are a great way to store sql queries, if spring support them.  I wouldn't know - I don't use it.

Comment: @mvb13 That is, continue with the old.

Comment: Store procedures + hibernate = a lot of pain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create Named query with your sql query and add to your hbm file or use `session.createSQLQuery()`

Use

```
session.createSQLQuery("Your native query here");
```

or

[NamedQuery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/querysql-namedqueries.html)

Add below named query file in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file

```
<mapping resource="CustomNamedQueries.hbm.xml"/>
```

In spring you should configured like below.

```
<property name="configLocations" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
```

Consider the following annotations in your model object.

```
@NamedNativeQuery
@NamedNativeQueries
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a properties file to store your SQL.

For example, create a properties file `custom_sql.properties`:

```
allUsers=select * from users;
```

Comment: properties file have the format of keys and values. For example searchAllUserSQL=select * from users. You could read the sql you are interested in from a properties file, call it customSQL.properties, and then execute it in you action classes or, better, in you service classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use namedQueries, that can be declared in hibernate configuration xml file. You can refer to [Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/) for example. Hoe this answers your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Create database view or views for the required data. You can then Map an entity to this view jast as if it was a table.

e.g.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public Class Customer{

   @OneToOne
   private CustomerSummaryData summaryData;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_summary_Data")//actually a view based on your complex SQL
public class CustomerSummaryData{

}
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I only need to know where have I to store sql queries inside my application.